# Rush cooldown time

Tags: fallout-shelter

Is there a formula? I want to know how long should I wait (online? offline?)

E.g. if I want to rush with lowest risk to fail, how long should I wait after each rush? Or if I rush multiple times and there is a big chance to fail - how long to wait until it's minimum again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a "slowpoke" medic (the one producing medpacks) with operation cycle over `10 min`. I've noticed, what after it produces stimpack on its own - he is back to `34%` (minimum incident chance for him).

So it's about `10 %` every `10 min` decrease. Assuming you are **always** keeping it at minimum.

In other words rush everything, exit game, wait 10 min, start game, rush everything, repeat for maximizing money income (without risk to fall into incidents/attacks in between).